# Is it possible to outrun a Winged Queen Slime?

Tags: terraria

Is it possible to outrun a Winged Queen Slime?

I know that the maximum horizontal speed is [around 240mph](https://terraria.wiki.gg/wiki/Movement_speed#Horizontal_speed)

But I don't have the gear to replicate it, nor do I want to spend a Gelatin Crystal trying, and at my current 41mph speed, it seems like it keeps accelerating when it takes off from landing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: Not without Asphalt.

Winged Queen Slime caught up to me when my speed was 68mph, but I outran her when it was 74mph, so I suspect her speed is 70mph.

I equipped all the gear you could have pre-mech:

- Cobalt Helmet
- Gi (from the Traveling Merchant)
- Cobalt Leggings
- Cake (from the Party Girl, for the Sugar Rush buff)
- Quick Frostspark Boots
- Quick Lightning Boots
- Quick Magiluminescence
- Quick Aglet
- Quick Fairy Wings
- Quick Anklet of the Wind
- Quick Moon Charm
- Swiftness Potion (for the Swiftness buff)
- Sunflower (for the Happy! buff)
- Apple Pie (for the Exquisitely Stuffed buff)

and after all of that? My speed only reached 57mph.
If I step on asphalt though, my speed jumps up to over 150mph!

Minecarts won't allow you to outrun her because they only have a maximum speed of 66mph pre-mech. But! Everytime she reaches you while you're in a minecart, she does her slam attack so while she's busy slamming the ground you can run away.

Comment: It seems like you're missing Sugar Rush? https://terraria.wiki.gg/wiki/Sugar_Rush

Also, it's Swiftness Potion, not Speed, apparently. https://terraria.wiki.gg/wiki/Swiftness_Potion

EDIT: Nevermind, you called it Cake. I misread.

Comment: @Malady Yeah I sometimes mix up the the thing giving the buff with the buff itself 

Comment: @Malady Here's a [link](https://youtu.be/rHacAZz7hVk) to a Queen Slime fight I did with this set-up. As you can see in 1:22 she does catch-up to me but she doesn't seem to be able to hit me or slam me for some reason

Comment: Cool! I saw her twitch at https://youtu.be/rHacAZz7hVk?t=88...

What Difficulty was that fight in? I wonder if she's faster at higher ones.

If you add anecdotes of "failure to slam" in your answer, I think I'll Check this, because it's very comprehensive on how to fight her.

Comment: @Malady that was in Master difficulty, ×1 spawn rate, normal world (not ftw or other special seeds)

Answer (score 0):

Back on the Xbox 360 I used to sometimes accidentally run so fast with an asphalt road and lightning boots I sometimes would despawn Duke Fishron by having them go off screen.

You make asphalt blocks at a Blend-O-Matic which you can buy from the Steampunker.

I don't remember if Winged Queen Slime is faster than Duke Fishron or not but asphalt helps a lot.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/318831)